# Using subl from the terminal on a mac

Tags: macos, terminal, sublimetext

I'm trying to make "subl" be a shortcut by creating a symlink: `ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl`

This path: `/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl` opens up the text editor.

But there is no subl in my `/usr/local/bin/` directory

So I tried to copy it there by entering `cp "/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin`

I get the error message `cp: /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl: No such file or directory` which doesn't make any sense because I JUST opened sublime using that path.

Comment: I also tried `sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/bin/subl`. It asks for my password then says operation not permitted.

Comment: What does `which subl` tell you?

Comment: @Bill Nothing, I think because there's no subl in my /usr/bin

Comment: Try `alias subl="open /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app"`

Comment: You could use an alias, e.g. `alias subl='/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'` in your `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: You're using Sublime Text 2. That information would have been useful.

Comment: @MattDMo I'm prettyyy sure I'm using Sublime Text 3.